# Spring - @PropertySource, getting an NPE ;(

Tags: java, spring

I'm having some trouble using `@PropertySource`, I get a NPE when using `env.getProperty(..)`.
Does anybody have any insight?

My environment:

- JDK/JRE: 1.6.0_06
- OS: Linux Mint 13
- Spring: 4.1.6.RELEASE

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.app.ExpressiveConfig.main(ExpressiveConfig.java:33)
```

The properties file `/src/main/resources/com/mycompany/app/app.properties`:

```
disc.title=Sgt.PeppersLonelyHeartsClubBand
disc.artist=TheBeatles
```

My config class:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@PropertySource("classpath:/com/mycompany/app/app.properties")
public class ExpressiveConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public App get() {
        return new App("hello", env.getProperty("disc.artist"));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        App a = new ExpressiveConfig().get();
    }

}
```

Model class:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

public class App {

      private final String title;
      private final String artist;

      public App(String title, String artist) {
        this.title = title;
        this.artist = artist;
      }

      public String getTitle() {
        return title;
      }

      public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
      }
}
```

Failed attempts:

1. I have tried playing around with the `@PropertySource` annotation, for example using the file: prefix and absolute path to the properties file.
   Dropping the backslash before the classpath eg/@PropertySource("classpath:com/mycompany/app/app.properties").
   Putting the properties file in different places.
2. I've also tried using `@PropertySources` containing an `@PropertySource` annotation too.
3. I've added:

   @Bean
   public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
   return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
   }

Any help/advice much appreciated!!

Comment: How are you initialising ExpressiveConfig?

Comment: Hava you tested : 
`@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will only inject dependencies into beans that it manages itself. Since you're creating that instance yourself (`new ExpressiveConfig()`), there will be no dependency injection performed as Spring is actually not involved at all.

You need to create an application context with a bean definition for that type and retrieve the instance from there.

To do that, annotate your `ExpressiveConfig` as a spring `@Configuration` and then, instead of instantiating it your self, just pass that class to an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. Then you'll be able to retrieve your beans from the context with `getBean(...)`.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.